# LINQPad MethodAccessException

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, linqpad

I'm trying to use EF 4.1 with LINQPad, but when I run a query I get the following error:

> MethodAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'LINQPadDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.String)' to access
>   method
>   'LINQPad.Extensibility.DataContext.EntityFrameworkDbContextDriver.CreateFactoryConnection(System.String,
>   System.Object)' failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in LINQPad's new EF driver which has been refactored to use Reflection.Emit to properly cope with both EF versions (4.1 and 4.2). I think I've tracked it down: try the 4.37.8 build and let me know.